# Shell Globbing - Issues with wildcard matching

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, terminal, matching

I am trying to write a pattern that will match any file name in a directory containing: a digit, immediately followed by a letter 'e' or 'h'.
(Example: 3e.txt)

I am required to test these patterns in the terminal/shell. I have tried writing several patterns, but they are all unable to find the 3e.txt and 3h.txt files that I have purposely placed in my working directory to test the patterns.

```
$ ls [0-9[e]*[h]*]?
$ ls [0-9][e]?
```

I am quite new to the shell, so I am not sure if I am using the wildcards correctly. How can I correct my pattern so it will match the file names I am searching for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most shell do not support regular expressions. You can pipe `ls` in `egrep` for pattern matching:

`$ ls | egrep '[0-9][eh]'`

Comment: Note that character sets (`[...]`) are a part of POSIX basic regular expression syntax, so there is no need to use ERE `grep` variant (i.e. `egrep`). Simply `grep` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` does not support regex syntax for patterns. You need to redirect `ls` output to some regex tool, for example grep:

```
ls | grep '[0-9][eh]'
```

Notice the pattern you need is actually `[0-9][eh]`, which is a digit followed by `e` or `h`.

This will list all files with a digit followed by `e` or `h` even in the middle of the name. If you need only files *starting* with this sequence, add `^` to the regex:

```
ls | grep '^[0-9][eh]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that should match patterns such as `3e.txt`, `2h.txt` but not `3eh.txt`.

```
ls | grep -P '\d[eh]\.\w{1,3}'
```

It means *"any digit suceed by a single 'e' or 'h' with a .xxx suffix"*.

## [Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/30VR4B/1)

Comment: You're using Perl syntax features in the regex, so should better make `grep` aware of it. Use `-P`: `ls | grep -P '\d[eh]\.\w{1,3}'`